# How to get the last number from list in python

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose I have the list as

```
a = [0.0021, 0.12, 0.1224, 0.22]
```

I have to extract the last number from the above list, so my answer should be `0.22` without using `a[3]`, because the number of the elements in the list always keep changing.

Comment: Consider reading about slicing.

Comment: Will the list ever contain non-numeric values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're talking about a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Arrays in python are usually [numpy.arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html). They are a completely different data structure.

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
>>> array = [0.0021, 0.12, 0.1224, 0.22]
>>> array[-1]
0.22
>>>
```

Negative indexing starts at the end of the list, thus `array[-1]` will always be the last element in the list, `array[-2]` the second last and so forth.

Comment: Please explain a bit more about how the negative indexing works.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate name of `[...]` is a *list*. As you know, you can access to an element of a list using an index, like

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
print some_list[0] # first element
```

But you can also use negative indices:

```
print some_list[-1] # last element: 3
print some_list[-2] # one before the last element: 2
```

Note that this will "count" elements *from right to left*

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry! Try them!

`a[len(a)-1]`

or

`a[-1]`